# Use Riesz theorem to show functional bounded

Tags: functional-analysis, vector-spaces

I have the linear functional:

$ F(v) = \int_\Gamma v \mathbf{g}\cdot\mathbf{n} d\Gamma$

where $\Gamma$ is a (smooth) part of the boundary of a domain $\Omega$, $\mathbf{g}$ is given (assumed smooth) and $\mathbf{n}$ is the unit normal on $\Gamma$. I'd like to show that $F(v)$ is bounded for all $v\in H^1(\Omega)$.

By Riesz representation theorem I can say that there is a unique $f\in H^1(\Omega)$ such that:

$ F(v) = (v, f)$

and that $||F|| = ||f||$. So if I can find this unique $f$ than I've shown that $F(v)$ is bounded.

Is it correct to say that $f = \mathbf{g}\cdot\mathbf{n}$ on $\Gamma$ and 0 everywhere else in $\Omega$? This does satisfy $F(v) = (v,f)$ as far as I can tell, but it seems like $f \notin H^1(\Omega)$. If that's the case, how would I find $f$?

Comment: $f$ does not have to be defined outside $\Gamma$ since the integral takes only over $\Gamma$. But you may need use the [trace theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sobolev_space#Traces) to estimate the $\|v\|_{L^2(\partial\Omega)}$.

Comment: Can you clarify? Are you saying that I should be using the trace theorem instead of the Riesz theorem?

Comment: I mean that the integral depends on the values on $\Gamma$, so you can estimate it by $L_2$ norms on $\Gamma$. However, you will need then to connect the boundary values of the Sobolev function $v$ on $\Gamma$ with values of $v$ (i.e. the norm) in the whole domain. That's where the trace theorem may be useful. Look at what it says and see if your $\Omega$ satisfies the condition.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> By Riesz representation theorem I can say ...

No you can't, because in the Riesz representation theorem, the functional is **assumed** to be bounded. This theorem doesn't help you prove that it's bounded.

Instead, follow the approach pointed out by A.G.: by the [trace theorem], the trace of $v$ on $\Gamma$ has $L^2$ norm bounded by $C\|v\|_{H^1(\Omega)}$ where $C$ is a constant that depends on $\Omega$ only. Then the Cauchy-Schwarz inequality implies 
$$
|F(v)| \le  \|v\|_{L^2(\Gamma)} \|\mathbf{g}\|_{L^2(\Gamma)}
\le C\|v\|_{H^1(\Omega)}\|\mathbf{g}\|_{L^2(\Gamma)}
$$
hence  $\|F\|\le C\|\mathbf{g}\|_{L^2(\Gamma)}<\infty$.